# Why do i get different results when i use lower() and when i not use lower()?

Tags: python, if-statement

**when i not use .lower(): I don't get the desired result**

```
name=input("Insert your name here: \n")
weight=float(input("Enter your weight here: \n"))
unit=input("What unit do you want to use? \n")

if unit == "kgs" or "KGS":
    print(f"{name} is {weight} kgs.")
elif unit == "LBS" or "lbs":
    convert=weight/2.2
    print(f"{name} is {convert} lbs.")
else:
    print("Please re-enter.")
```

**when I use .lower(): I got the desired result**

```
name=input("Insert your name here: \n")
weight=float(input("Enter your weight here: \n"))
unit=input("What unit do you want to use? \n")

if unit.lower() == "kgs":
    print(f"{name} is {weight} kgs.")
elif unit.lower()== "lbs":
    convert=weight/2.2
    print(f"{name} is {convert} lbs.")
else:
    print("Please re-enter.")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true which has an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if unit == "kgs" or "KGS":
```

to

```
if unit == "kgs" or unit == "KGS":
```

You have to write complete expressions on both sides of the `or` for the entire expression to evaluate the way you expect it to.

Using `lower` in this case is better though, since it also catches cases where the user types in 'Kgs', for example.

Answer (score 0):

It has least to do with `.lower()`, you are not using the `unit` var in the complete expression.

Change this:

```
if unit == "kgs" or "KGS":
```

to this (using the `unit`in the both sides of the `or` operator):

```
if unit == "kgs" or unit == "KGS":
```